# Horizontal scrolling of a ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I'll show my goal: I have an ExpandableListView (ELV) to show a lot of key-values, grouped by categories. Groups of ELV are categories and every key-value is a new child in ELV. Every child is just a TextView ("key : value") that I want to show **in a single line**
So, my ELV has *layout_width* and *layout_height* to *wrap_content*, and in *getGroupView* and *getChildView* (ELV adapter) I create a TextView and set *setSingleLine*

This setup works OK but when some child is larger than screen I cannot see it entirely. So I need some mechanism for horizontal scrolling, and I added a HorizontalScrollView (HSV) wrapping the ELV (because I want to scroll the whole ELV, not only the child oversized). But this solution has a very strange behaviour: the *layout_width* is something like ignored... I mean, the whole ELV takes the width of the first group item and ignores the rest of items (they are cut).

XML
`<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#550000" >
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/MI_tree2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#555555"
        android:childDivider="#00000000" >
    </ExpandableListView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>`

To see the space filled by HSV and ELV I have put them a background. Here you have two snapshots, one without HSV and a the normal size behaviour (1) and other with HSV and the strange size behaviour (2)

(1) https://www.dropbox.com/s/b63rpflk5q1ktyc/Screenshot_2014-03-31-21-24-40.png
(2) https://www.dropbox.com/s/etkra8e8hx3ueak/Screenshot_2014-03-31-21-18-32.png

What do you recommend me? There is something wrong in my code? There is another simpler way?
Thanks

EDIT: For some unknown reason, everything I try to set width programmatically is ignored too.

Comment: yeah, Android doesn't want to have to measure every item in your list to determine the widest one when sizing the ELV to "wrap_content". I suppose in your GetGroupView and GetChildView code you could see if the TextView you are rendering is wider than the previous widest one, and resize (widen) the ELV in code.

Comment: I'll try your recommend but, in fact, Android DOES measure ELV to the wider item by itself when no HSV is present. See snapshot (1). The problem comes when I wrap ELV inside the HSV (2)

Comment: Android needs to do size calculations at layout time and the varying width in your situation might confuse things. What if you just implement a click event on the list view and show the contents of the row in an alert dialog? This will keep things simple and the user only needs to click if they want to see more.

Comment: @RobP I have done what you recommend me. For some unknown reason, everything I try to set width programmatically is ignored.

Comment: after you set the width are you calling invalidate() or something to force a redraw?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/sivailango/ExpandableListView-RecylerChildItems